# tracking sensitive data in memory from my WPF application and C# libraries

Tags: c#, security, debugging, securestring

I've been trying to go through a couple of my C# libraries and a WPF application that uses them and replace plain-text, string passwords with `SecureString`.  I do have to convert a `SecureString` back to a regular string in some places to interact with other libraries/web services over which I have no control, but I want to minimize the amount that I do that.  I'm also trying to follow [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fpintos/archive/2009/06/12/how-to-properly-convert-securestring-to-string.aspx) about how to do it correctly.  Is there an easy way to monitor what strings end up floating around in memory from my code?  I'd like to know how many points of weakness, so to speak, there are in my code with respect to sensitive data being in plain-text in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing you can check is if your plaintext password is kept alive by the library, by adding a weak reference to it, and see how long it takes to go away. You can check if it helps to do some amount of forced garbage collect from time to time. But avoid doing forced GC in production code, especcially on servers.

But that's only half the problem: it depends mostly on what the other libraries do with your string. If they embed the password in some other string, and keep it referenced, it will be unsecured in memory without you having control over it.

Comment: So if my test password were "pass123", I would add a WeakReference (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.weakreference(v=VS.90).aspx) to "pass123", and since strings are immutable in .NET, if any other code makes use of "pass123"...  Wait, what do I do with the WeakReference?  Put a watch on it in the debugger?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea generally. After the library call, you put the ref to the string in weakref, set the original string ref to null, and then you can try if a global forced GC will make it go away. If causes it to dissappear you know the library is at least not keeping your secret string alive indefinetly. Next step could be to test in a debug build every so many seconds/minutes how long it takes for your string to get garbage collected. You keep the weakref around, and check when it's Target turns to null.

Comment: In general, the longer you keep your string alive initially, the longer it will take to get collected after that. If your api calls take a long time or trigger the GC often, .net may have decided your string appears to be long lasting, and will only destroy it when a full GC happens. In a GUI application, it might be acceptable to trigger these yourself, for example when your app turns idle.